# How to remove duplicates from particular column in Scala by reading textfile

Tags: scala

I am new to scala, I am reading textfile from local, and I want to find duplicate columns in example.

Input File:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
1,3,4
2,4,5
3,4,5
```

I need output like this:

Select first column

```
1->2
2->3
3->1
```

program is:

```
val file=scala.io.Source.fromFile("D:/Files/test.txt").getLines().mkString("\n")
val d=file.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
println(d)
```

But I am getting output Like this

```
Map(-> 5, 4 -> 1, 9 -> 1, 5 -> 3, , -> 12, 1 -> 3, 0 -> 1, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 4)
```

Its counting all the data but I want to count duplicates in particualr column only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, shouldn't the duplicate counts of the 1st column be `(1->2, 2->2, 3->1)`?

Here's one approach to get the counts:

```
// Create a list of split-column arrays
val list = scala.io.Source.
  fromFile("/Users/leo/projects/scala/files/testfile.txt").
  getLines.
  map(_.split(",")).
  toList

list: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2, 3, 4), Array(1, 3, 4), Array(2, 4, 5), Array(3, 4, 5))

// Count duplicates of the 1st split-column
val d = list.
  groupBy(_(0)).
  mapValues(_.size)

d: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1)
```

Comment: Working FIne Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is because once the call `mkString` is made, the multiple lines on the file is 'lost'. Another approach could be to use the `toArray` call instead.

```
val file = scala.io.Source.fromFile("D:/Files/test.txt")
val lines = file.getLines().toArray
```

On the above example, `lines` would be a array of strings:

```
Array(1,2,3, 2,3,4, 1,3,4, 2,4,5, 3,4,5)
```

then to extract the first column before grouping you could use something like the `slice` method on each string

```
lines.map(_.slice(0,1)).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

Also, remember to close the file :)

Full example:

```
val file = scala.io.Source.fromFile("D:/Files/test.txt")
val lines = file.getLines().toArray
val grouping = lines.map(_.slice(0,1)).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)

file.close
```

Comment: Everything is fine but after running this code I am getting output as hashcode not the output.

Comment: ([Ljava.lang.String;@64fe7a67,1)
([Ljava.lang.String;@ea211cf,1)
([Ljava.lang.String;@5438ebc3,1)
([Ljava.lang.String;@1e3bd51,1)

Comment: Interesting, I get the same data structure as running the accepted code: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]

Comment: Dont Know  Any how Thanks for your reply bro

Comment: How to learn scala more more deeply which is the best sites to learn more deep core of scala

Comment: I Dont understand few concepts in Scala like Implicit parameter and closure